# How to sort one to many collection and order by on the same column using hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities like this -

```
Product {
@OneToMany(...)
List<State> states;
}
```

```
State {
String code;
}
```

Values of states would be e.g - {"AL", "TX", "WA"}, {"CA"}.

I need to support both ascending and descending order as per request. So cant use @OrderBy annotation. As per direction provided in request, I need to sort each entry in collection and then apply order by on entire column. So above example would sort like -
{"CA"}, {"AL", "TX", "WA"} for descending and reverse for asceding.

Any insights would be helpful.